# Подключение к базе данных MongoDB

Tags: windows, node.js

Пытаюсь подключить в исполняемый файл модуль require('mongoose'); и сразу выдаётся ошибка.

```js
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aquarius\Desktop\Node\public\Meadowlark\node
_modules\bson\ext\index.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

Comment: Ответ уже ранее опубликован на зарубежной платформе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144030/using-mongodb-with-node-js

Comment: @Netahaki На сколько я понял mongoose уже не поддерживается для node js. Если не правильно понял поправте пожалуйста.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson